# move_base with multiple robots running gmapping SLAM on turtlebot3

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run move_base nodes for each of 3 turtlebot3s in ROS melodic and gazebo9. My approach is taken mainly from the ["Multiple robots simulation and navigation"](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/#41434) answer which gives instructions on how to simulate multiple turtlebot3s (3 in my case) using AMCL package and the navigation stack. [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) package "track the pose of a robot against a known map" but in this case I am running gmapping SLAM on my 3 turtlebot3s. I am not using amcl package because I am using gmapping SLAM to do my localization and map building.

My objective is to run explore_lite on 3 turtlebot3s and using [multirobot_map_merge](http://wiki.ros.org/multirobot_map_merge) to merge their individual maps. For now, I am trying to run move_base for each of the 3 turtlebot3s and use '2D Nav Goal' for each of their /move_base_simple/goal topics. When I run my  multi_move_base.launch file, I get the following error:

```
[ WARN] [1676956640.385330213, 617.147000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: source_frame base_footprint does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.101 timeout was 0.1.
```

I am not able to solve this error. Here are my launch files:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo multi_MAIN_turtlebot3.launch
```

uses `multi_MAIN_turtlebot3.launch`:

```
<launch>
  <!-- <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/> -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3"  default="tb3_0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3" default="tb3_1"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3"  default="tb3_2"/>

  <arg name="first_tb3_x_pos" default="-7.0"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_y_pos" default="-1.0"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_z_pos" default=" 0.0"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_yaw"   default=" 1.57"/>

  <arg name="second_tb3_x_pos" default=" 7.0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_y_pos" default="-1.0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_z_pos" default=" 0.0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_yaw"   default=" 1.57"/>

  <arg name="third_tb3_x_pos" default=" 0.5"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3_y_pos" default=" 3.0"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3_z_pos" default=" 0.0"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3_yaw"   default=" 0.0"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/turtlebot3_house.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>  

  <group ns = "$(arg first_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg first_tb3)" />
    </node>
    
    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg first_tb3) -x $(arg first_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg first_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg first_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg first_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

  <group ns = "$(arg second_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg second_tb3)" />
    </node>

    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg second_tb3) -x $(arg second_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg second_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg second_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg second_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

  <group ns = "$(arg third_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg third_tb3)" />
    </node>

    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg third_tb3) -x $(arg third_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg third_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg third_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg third_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

</launch>
```

`roslaunch turtlebot3_slam multi_gmapping.launch`

uses `multi_gmapping.launch`:

```
 <launch>
  <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

  <!-- Launch the gmapping node for Turtlebot 3 with custom namespace -->
  <!-- <group ns="tb3_0"> -->
    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/multi_turtlebot3_slam.launch">
      <arg name="ns" value="tb3_0"/>
    </include>
  <!-- </group> -->

  <!-- <group ns="tb3_1"> -->
    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/multi_turtlebot3_slam.launch">
      <arg name="ns" value="tb3_1"/>
    </include>
  <!-- </group> -->

  <!-- <group ns="tb3_2"> -->
    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/multi_turtlebot3_slam.launch">
      <arg name="ns" value="tb3_2"/>
    </include>
  <!-- </group> -->

  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/multi_map_merge.launch"></include>

  <group if="$(arg open_rviz)"> 
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
          args="-d $(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/rviz/multi_turtlebot3_slam_MB.rviz"/>
  </group>

</launch>
```

`multi_turtlebot3_slam.launch`:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="ns" default="tb3_0"/>

  <!-- Gmapping -->
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="turtlebot3_slam_gmapping" output="screen" ns="$(arg ns)">
    <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg ns)/base_footprint"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg ns)/odom"/>
    <param name="map_frame"  value="$(arg ns)/map"/>
    <param name="map_update_interval" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="maxUrange" value="4.0"/>
    <param name="minimumScore" value="100"/>
    <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="temporalUpdate" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="lskip" value="0"/>
    <param name="particles" value="120"/>
    <param name="sigma" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
    <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
    <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
    <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
    <param name="srr" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="srt" value="0.02"/>
    <param name="str" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="stt" value="0.02"/>
    <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="xmin" value="-10.0"/>
    <param name="ymin" value="-10.0"/>
    <param name="xmax" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="ymax" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
    <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

`roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation multi_move_base.launch`

uses `multi_move_base.launch`:

```
<launch>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>



    <!-- Launch the move_base node for Turtlebot 3 with custom namespace -->
  <group ns="tb3_0">
    <!-- <param name="tf_prefix" value="tb3_0" /> -->
    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/move_base.launch">

        <arg name="cmd_vel_topic" value="tb3_0/cmd_vel" />
        <arg name="odom_topic" value="tb3_0/odom" />
        <arg name="move_forward_only" value="false"/>
    </include> 
  </group>

  <group ns="tb3_1">
    <!-- <param name="tf_prefix" value="tb3_1" /> -->
    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/move_base.launch">

        <arg name="cmd_vel_topic" value="tb3_1/cmd_vel" />
        <arg name="odom_topic" value="tb3_1/odom" />
        <arg name="move_forward_only" value="false"/>
    </include>
  </group>

  <group ns="tb3_2">
    <!-- <param name="tf_prefix" value="tb3_2" /> -->
    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/move_base.launch">

        <arg name="cmd_vel_topic" value="tb3_2/cmd_vel" />
        <arg name="odom_topic" value="tb3_2/odom" />
        <arg name="move_forward_only" value="false"/>
    </include>
  </group>

</launch>
```

and finally, my `move_base.launch`:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="cmd_vel_topic" default="/cmd_vel" />
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/dwa_local_planner_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="$(arg cmd_vel_topic)"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    <remap from="map" to="/map" />
    <remap from="base_footprint" to="/base_footprint" />
    <param name="DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x" value="0.0" if="$(arg move_forward_only)" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412698/move_base-with-multiple-robots-running-gmapping-slam-on-turtlebot3/) by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24 on 2023-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The names of the map topics do not appear to match.

The map topic that move_base is trying to subscribe to is /map.
In contrast, the map topic published by gmapping should be /tb3_1/map etc., not /map.

There is progress to be made in aligning them.
You could try removing `<remap from="map" to="/map" />` from move_base.launch.

Before you do that, we recommend that you check the list of topics to see who the publisher and subscribers are.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2023-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-03-01**:
This helps. So previously my `move_base_simple/goal` for each turtlebot3 was being set on the global /map topic. This is undesired because the /map is a result of the combination of `/tb3_0/map, /tb3_1/map,` and `/tb3_2/map` using multirobot_map_merge package. When I removed `<remap from="map" to="/map" />` the `move_base_simple/goal` for each turtlebot3 was sent to /tb3_0/map, /tb3_1/map,`and`/tb3_2/map` respectively.